# How to cache a base64 encoded image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, base64, image-caching

I have used `Image.memory(base64Decode(encodedString, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: imgWidth,height: imgHeight)` to load a base64 encoded image in flutter. In a listview viewing the images causes a flickering. Bcoz each time, the image is loaded again and again for each item in the list. So is there any way to cache a base64 encoded image in flutter?

Comment: try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html

Comment: @pskink Tried with `MemoryImage-class` still issue persists.

Comment: where do you call `MemoryImage` constructor?

Comment: @pskink Like this `Image(image: MemoryImage(base64Decode(encodedString)))`

Comment: call it once, for example inside `State.initState` method

Comment: @pskink The `encodedString` is different for each item in the list. The images are different for almost every items in the list. So calling it only once won't work.

Comment: `List<MemoryImage> listOfImages = ...`

Comment: Could u please explain @pskink?

Comment: use a list, of `MemoryImage`, not one `MemoryImage` - that list will store several `MemoryImage` each one made from different base64 string

Comment: or even better use `Map`, not `List`

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lott.. It worked.. If u can answer to this post it would be helpful to others too.

Comment: good, go ahead and write a self answer...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling MemoryImage inside `Widget build()`, you can initialize the base64 images inside `initState()`.

```dart
late List<MemoryImage> _listImages;

@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  
  // load images here
  _listImages.add(MemoryImage(imageData));
}
```

This should prevent the "flickering" happening on the widgets since the Screen is usually refreshed when the state has been changed.